# Want to update old doc, duplicate old doc + 1 month and rerun function if duplicated doc is more then 1 month old. Using firebase and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm making a expense tracker (practice project) and want to add monthly recurring expenses, when a user creates an expense there is an option to set recurring to true.

The function I made looks at expenseData and sees if (recurring == true) and if (date <= 1 month old), then creates a new expense with the old expenseData and adds 1 to the month, then updates the old expenseData with recurring == false.

I think the problem lies with the function works fine but it isn't waiting (not wrapped in useEffect) for the new/updated data from firebase.

- What I've tried

  1. Wrapping addRecuring() in useEffect: This only runs once.
  2. Wrapping addRecuring() in useEffect, setting a state to true if function conditions are true and adding it to the dependancy "[]": This only runs once.
  3. Not wrapping addRecuring() in useEffect: This makes too many new double duplicates (where recurring == true), which causes them to do them same.
  4. Wrapping addRecuring() in useEffect and changing code while browser is live: Adds and updates with each change but obviously not a solution.

1. addRecurring() function:

   ````
      const addRecurring = () => {  
          console.log("starting recurring");

          for (let i = 0; i < expenseData.length; i++) {
              let expenseDate = new Date(expenseData[i].date.slice(0, 10));
              let oneMonthBeforeToday = new Date(monthBeforeDate);
              const twoYearsAgo = -63372000000;
              // console.log({expenseDate})
              // console.log({oneMonthBeforeToday})
              // console.log(expenseDate - oneMonthBeforeToday)
              // 63072000000 milliseconds == 2 years
              if (
                  expenseData[i].recurring === true &&
                  expenseDate - oneMonthBeforeToday <= 0 &&
                  expenseDate - oneMonthBeforeToday > twoYearsAgo
              ) { 

                  //  console.log({ expenseDate });
                  let newDate = new Date(
                      expenseDate.setMonth(expenseDate.getMonth() + 1)
                  );
                  let getDay = newDate.toString().slice(8, 10);
                  // console.log({ getDay });
                  let getMonth = newDate.toString().slice(4, 7);
                  // console.log({ getMonth });
                  let getMonthNum = monthToNumber(getMonth);
                  //console.log({ getMonthNum });
                  let getYear = newDate.toString().slice(11, 15);
                  // console.log({ getYear });
                  let newDateFormatted = `${getYear}-${getMonthNum}-${getDay}`;
                  console.log({ newDateFormatted });
                  addDoc(expenseDataRef, {
                      title: expenseData[i].title,
                      type: expenseData[i].type,
                      amount: expenseData[i].amount,
                      date: newDateFormatted,
                      created: serverTimestamp(),
                      recurring: true,
                      key: nanoid(),
                      uid: user.uid,
                      email: user.email,
                  });
                  const updateCurrent = doc(
                      db,
                      "expenseData",
                      expenseData[i].id
                  );
                  updateDoc(updateCurrent, {
                      // title:expenseData[i].title,
                      // type:expenseData[i].type,
                      // amount:expenseData[i].amount,
                      date: expenseData[i].date,
                      recurring: false,
                      hasRecurred: true,
                      recurredDate: newDateFormatted,
                  });
                 // setRefresh(!refresh)
              }
          } 
      };
      addRecurring()
   }, []); ```
   ````
2. getExpenseData() function:

   ````
       console.log("getting data");
       const userUid = user.uid;
       const getExpenseData = async () => {
           const unsub = await onSnapshot(
               query(
                   expenseDataRef,
                   where("uid", "==", userUid),
                   orderBy("date", "desc")
               ),
               (snapshot) => {
                   setExpenseData(
                       snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                           ...doc.data(),
                           id: doc.id,
                       }))
                   );
               }
           );

           return unsub;
       };
       getExpenseData();

   }, []); ```
   ````
3. Full Expense.js file (not sure why the first line ( export const Expenses = () => {  )imports won't go in code block):

   ```
   const { user } = useAuth();
   const [userDisplayName, setUserDisplayName] = useState(user.displayName);
   const [expenseData, setExpenseData] = useState([]);
   const [dataTitle, setDataTitle] = useState();
   const [dataAmount, setDataAmount] = useState(0);
   const [dataType, setDataType] = useState();
   const [dataDate, setDataDate] = useState();
   const [dataRecurring, setDataRecurring] = useState("off");
   const expenseDataRef = collection(db, "expenseData");
   const [editBtnId, setEditBtnId] = useState();
   const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);

   const handleCurrentId = (e) => {
       setEditBtnId(e.currentTarget.id);
   };
   const handleCreateData = async () => {
       await addDoc(expenseDataRef, {
           title: dataTitle,
           type: dataType,
           amount: dataAmount,
           date: dataDate,
           created: serverTimestamp(),
           recurring: dataRecurring,
           key: nanoid(),
           uid: user.uid,
           email: user.email,
       });
       setDataRecurring("off");
       //setRefresh(!refresh);
   };
   const handleEditData = async () => {
       const updateCurrent = doc(db, "expenseData", editBtnId);
       await updateDoc(updateCurrent, {
           title: dataTitle,
           type: dataType,
           amount: dataAmount,
           date: dataDate,
           recurring: dataRecurring,

           id: editBtnId,
           editDate: serverTimestamp(),
       });
       setDataRecurring("off");
   };
   const handleDeleteData = async () => {
       await deleteDoc(doc(db, "expenseData", editBtnId));
   };
   const [currentExpense, setCurrentExpense] = useState([]);
   //when mouse enters the edit buttons parent div, it grabs it's id and compares it to expenseData id to make sure user edits/deletes the one they clicked on
   const changeExpense = () => {
       for (let i = 0; i < expenseData.length; i++) {
           if (expenseData[i].id === editBtnId) {
               setCurrentExpense(expenseData[i]);
               setDataTitle(expenseData[i].title);
               setDataAmount(expenseData[i].amount);
               setDataType(expenseData[i].type);
               setDataDate(expenseData[i].date);
               setDataRecurring(expenseData[i].recurring);
           }
       }
   };
   useEffect(() => {
       console.log("getting data");
       const userUid = user.uid;
       const getExpenseData = async () => {
           const unsub = await onSnapshot(
               query(
                   expenseDataRef,
                   where("uid", "==", userUid),
                   orderBy("date", "desc")
               ),
               (snapshot) => {
                   setExpenseData(
                       snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                           ...doc.data(),
                           id: doc.id,
                       }))
                   );
               }
           );

           return unsub;
       };
       getExpenseData();

   }, []);

   console.log(expenseData);
   //RECURRING ZONE************************
   const monthToNumber = (getMonth) => {
       let monthNumber = "";
       if (getMonth === "Jan") {
           monthNumber = "01";
       } else if (getMonth === "Feb") {
           monthNumber = "02";
       } else if (getMonth === "Mar") {
           monthNumber = "03";
       } else if (getMonth === "Apr") {
           monthNumber = "04";
       } else if (getMonth === "May") {
           monthNumber = "05";
       } else if (getMonth === "Jun") {
           monthNumber = "06";
       } else if (getMonth === "Jul") {
           monthNumber = "07";
       } else if (getMonth === "Aug") {
           monthNumber = "08";
       } else if (getMonth === "Sep") {
           monthNumber = "09";
       } else if (getMonth === "Oct") {
           monthNumber = "10";
       } else if (getMonth === "Nov") {
           monthNumber = "11";
       } else if (getMonth === "Dec") {
           monthNumber = "12";
       }
       return monthNumber;
   };

   const monthBeforeDate = moment().subtract(1, "months").format("YYYY-MM-DD");

   //NEED TO: find a way to run more then once but not to fast so no double ups
   useEffect(() => {

       const addRecurring = () => {  
           console.log("starting recurring");

           for (let i = 0; i < expenseData.length; i++) {
               let expenseDate = new Date(expenseData[i].date.slice(0, 10));
               let oneMonthBeforeToday = new Date(monthBeforeDate);
               const twoYearsAgo = -63372000000;
               // console.log({expenseDate})
               // console.log({oneMonthBeforeToday})
               // console.log(expenseDate - oneMonthBeforeToday)
               // 63072000000 milliseconds == 2 years
               if (
                   expenseData[i].recurring === true &&
                   expenseDate - oneMonthBeforeToday <= 0 &&
                   expenseDate - oneMonthBeforeToday > twoYearsAgo
               ) { 

                   //  console.log({ expenseDate });
                   let newDate = new Date(
                       expenseDate.setMonth(expenseDate.getMonth() + 1)
                   );
                   let getDay = newDate.toString().slice(8, 10);
                   // console.log({ getDay });
                   let getMonth = newDate.toString().slice(4, 7);
                   // console.log({ getMonth });
                   let getMonthNum = monthToNumber(getMonth);
                   //console.log({ getMonthNum });
                   let getYear = newDate.toString().slice(11, 15);
                   // console.log({ getYear });
                   let newDateFormatted = `${getYear}-${getMonthNum}-${getDay}`;
                   console.log({ newDateFormatted });
                   addDoc(expenseDataRef, {
                       title: expenseData[i].title,
                       type: expenseData[i].type,
                       amount: expenseData[i].amount,
                       date: newDateFormatted,
                       created: serverTimestamp(),
                       recurring: true,
                       key: nanoid(),
                       uid: user.uid,
                       email: user.email,
                   });
                   const updateCurrent = doc(
                       db,
                       "expenseData",
                       expenseData[i].id
                   );
                   updateDoc(updateCurrent, {
                       // title:expenseData[i].title,
                       // type:expenseData[i].type,
                       // amount:expenseData[i].amount,
                       date: expenseData[i].date,
                       recurring: false,
                       hasRecurred: true,
                       recurredDate: newDateFormatted,
                   });
                  // setRefresh(!refresh)
               }
           } 
       };
       addRecurring()
   }, []);


   // addRecurring();

   // const jobs = [
   //     {
   //         fn: addRecurring(),
   //         id: "1",
   //         schedule: "* * * * *",
   //     },
   // ];
   // ********************************************** */

   const offsetPopup = {
       right: 400,
       bottom: 50,
   };
   const hasItRecurred = !currentExpense.hasRecurred ? (
       <span>
           <input
               className="recurring"
               name="recurring"
               onChange={(event) => {
                   setDataRecurring(event.target.checked);
               }}
               type="checkbox"
               defaultChecked={currentExpense.recurring}
           ></input>
           <label>Recurring</label>
       </span>
   ) : (
       <span>
           {currentExpense.title} recurred on {currentExpense.recurredDate}
       </span>
   );
   const createPopup = (
       <Popup
           modal={true}
           closeOnDocumentClick
           offset={offsetPopup}
           show={true}
           className="popup-main"
           // onClose={createClose}
           // onOpen={createOpen}
           trigger={
               <button className="create-expense-btn">
                   <img
                       src={create}
                       className="create-icon"
                       alt="create expense icon"
                   />
                   Create Expense
               </button>
           }
       >
           {(close) => (
               <div className="popup--container">
                   <input
                       onChange={(event) => {
                           setDataTitle(event.target.value);
                       }}
                       className="popup-title"
                       placeholder="Title"
                   ></input>
                   <input
                       onChange={(event) => {
                           setDataAmount(event.target.value);
                       }}
                       type="number"
                       className="popup-amount"
                       placeholder="Amount"
                   ></input>
                   <select
                       onChange={(event) => {
                           setDataType(event.target.value);
                       }}
                       className="popup-select"
                       name="type"
                       id="type"
                   >
                       <option defaultValue="" disabled selected>
                           Select your option
                       </option>
                       <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
                       <option value="Entertainment">Entertainment</option>
                       <option value="Software">Software</option>
                       <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                       <option value="Withdraw">Withdraw</option>
                       <option value="Payment">Payment</option>
                   </select>
                   <span>
                       <input
                           onChange={(event) => {
                               setDataDate(event.target.value);
                           }}
                           className="popup-date"
                           type="datetime-local"
                           placeholder="Title"
                       ></input>
                       <input
                           className="recurring"
                           name="recurring"
                           onChange={(event) => {
                               setDataRecurring(event.target.checked);
                           }}
                           type="checkbox"
                       ></input>
                       <label>Recurring</label>
                   </span>
                   <button
                       className="popup-add"
                       onClick={() => {
                           handleCreateData();
                           close();
                       }}
                   >
                       Add
                   </button>
               </div>
           )}
       </Popup>
   );
   const editPopup = (
       <Popup
           modal={true}
           offset={offsetPopup}
           show={false}
           closeOnDocumentClick
           className="popup-main"
           nested
           trigger={
               <button
                   onMouseDown={changeExpense}
                   className="edit-expense-btn"
               >
                   Edit
               </button>
           }
       >
           {(close) => (
               <div className="popup--container">
                   <input
                       onChange={(event) => {
                           setDataTitle(event.target.value);
                       }}
                       className="popup-title"
                       placeholder={currentExpense.title}
                       // value={currentExpense.title}
                   ></input>
                   <input
                       onChange={(event) => {
                           setDataAmount(event.target.value);
                       }}
                       type="number"
                       className="popup-amount"
                       placeholder={currentExpense.amount}
                       // value={currentExpense.amount}
                   ></input>
                   <select
                       onChange={(event) => {
                           setDataType(event.target.value);
                       }}
                       className="popup-select"
                       name="type"
                       // value={currentExpense.type}

                       id="type"
                   >
                       <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
                       <option value="Entertainment">Entertainment</option>
                       <option value="Software">Software</option>
                       <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
                       <option value="Withdraw">Withdraw</option>
                       <option value="Payment">Payment</option>
                   </select>
                   <span>
                       <input
                           onChange={(event) => {
                               setDataDate(event.target.value);
                           }}
                           className="popup-date"
                           type="datetime-local"
                           value={currentExpense.date}
                       ></input>
                       {hasItRecurred}
                   </span>
                   <button
                       className="popup-edit"
                       onClick={() => {
                           handleEditData();
                           close();
                       }}
                   >
                       Edit
                   </button>
                   <Popup
                       trigger={
                           <button className="popup-delete">Delete</button>
                       }
                       position="top"
                   >
                       <div className="RUSure-container">
                           <p>Are you sure?</p>
                           <span>
                               {" "}
                               <button
                                   className="RUSure-yes-btn"
                                   onClick={() => {
                                       handleDeleteData();
                                       close();
                                   }}
                               >
                                   Yes
                               </button>
                               <button
                                   className="RUSure-no-btn"
                                   onClick={close}
                               >
                                   No
                               </button>
                           </span>
                       </div>
                   </Popup>
               </div>
           )}
       </Popup>
   );
   //console.log(expenseData.map((data) => data.id));
   //rows of expense data
   const expenseDataElements = expenseData.map((data) => (
       <div className="row-data">
           <div>
               <p>{data.title}</p>
           </div>
           <div>
               <p>{data.type}</p>
           </div>
           <div>
               <p>${data.amount}</p>
           </div>
           <div>
               <p>{data.date.substring(0, 10)}</p>
           </div>
           <div>
               <p>{data.id}</p>
           </div>
           <div onMouseEnter={handleCurrentId} id={data.id}>
               {editPopup}
           </div>
       </div>
   ));
   return (
       <div className="expenses--container">
           <div className="expenses-nav">
               <div className="nav-line1">
                   <h1>Expenses</h1>
                   <h4>
                       <img
                           src={userIcon}
                           alt="user icon"
                           className="user-icon"
                       />
                       {userDisplayName}
                   </h4>
               </div>
               <div className="nav-line2">
                   <div className="nav-line2-left">
                       <button className="search-btn">
                           <img
                               src={magnifyingGlass}
                               alt="magnifying glass icon"
                           />
                       </button>
                       <input className="search" placeholder="Search"></input>
                   </div>
                   <div className="nav-line2-right">
                       {createPopup}
                       <button className="filter-btn">
                           <img
                               src={filter}
                               alt="filter -icon"
                               className="filter-icon"
                           />
                           Filters
                       </button>
                   </div>
               </div>

               <div className="row-header">
                   <p>NAME/BUSINESS</p>
                   <p>TYPE</p>
                   <p>AMOUNT</p>
                   <p>DATE</p>
                   <p>INVOICE ID</p>
                   <p>ACTION</p>
               </div>
               {expenseDataElements}
               {/* <Schedule
                   jobs={jobs}
                   timeZone="UTC"
                   dashboard={{ hidden: true }}
               /> */}
           </div>
       </div>
   );};
   ```

````
4. import list and first line:
    ``` import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
//import "react-schedule-job/dist/index.css";
import "./Expenses.css";
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";
import "reactjs-popup/dist/index.css";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";
import { db } from "../../firebase-config";
import { useAuth } from "../../Auth";
import magnifyingGlass from "../icons/magnifyingGlass.png";
import filter from "../icons/filter.png";
import create from "../icons/create.png";
import userIcon from "../icons/userIcon.png";
//import Schedule from "react-schedule-job";
import moment from "moment";

import {
    collection,
    getDocs,
    addDoc,
    updateDoc,
    doc,
    deleteDoc,
    query,
    orderBy,
    where,
    onSnapshot,
    serverTimestamp,
} from "firebase/firestore";

export const Expenses = () => { ```
````

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same problem, I put another query in the same useEffect so it has to get the data before it proceeds with the for loop and added setRedo(!redo) if the conditions where true and then added it to the dependencies.  setRedo(!redo) was also added to create and edit functions.

Not sure this is the best option as it seems expensive on the getDocs firebase.

````
```   const monthBeforeDate = moment().subtract(1, "months").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
useEffect(() => {
    const getExpenseData = async () => {
        const data = await getDocs(
            query(
                expenseDataRef,
                where("uid", "==", user.uid),
                where("recurring", "==", true),
                orderBy("date", "desc")
            )
        );
        const expenseData = data.docs.map((doc) => ({
            ...doc.data(),
            id: doc.id,
        }));
        for (let i = 0; i < expenseData.length; i++) {
            let expenseDate = new Date(expenseData[i].date.slice(0, 10));
            let oneMonthBeforeToday = new Date(monthBeforeDate);
            const twoYearsAgo = -63372000000;
            if (
                expenseData[i].recurring === true &&
                expenseDate - oneMonthBeforeToday <= 0 &&
                expenseDate - oneMonthBeforeToday > twoYearsAgo
            ) {

                let newDate = new Date(
                    expenseDate.setMonth(expenseDate.getMonth() + 1)
                );
                let getDay = newDate.toString().slice(8, 10);
                let getMonth = newDate.toString().slice(4, 7);
                let getMonthNum = monthToNumber(getMonth);
                let getYear = newDate.toString().slice(11, 15);
                let newDateFormatted = `${getYear}-${getMonthNum}-${getDay}`;
                addDoc(expenseDataRef, {
                    title: expenseData[i].title,
                    type: expenseData[i].type,
                    amount: expenseData[i].amount,
                    date: newDateFormatted,
                    created: serverTimestamp(),
                    recurring: true,
                    key: nanoid(),
                    uid: user.uid,
                    email: user.email,
                });
                const updateCurrent = await doc(
                    db,
                    "expenseData",
                    expenseData[i].id
                );
                updateDoc(updateCurrent, {
                    date: expenseData[i].date,
                    recurring: false,
                    hasRecurred: true,
                    recurredDate: newDateFormatted,
                    //incomeOrExpense: expenseData[i].incomeOrExpense,
                });
                setRedo(!redo);
            }
        }
    };
    getExpenseData();
}, [redo]); ```
````